# VBa Looping through RecordSets is too slow for my program

Tags: multithreading, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a RecordSet loop inside another RecordSet loop. It'd work well if it didn't take 45 secs for the .OpenRecordSet to run, and the table it'll open has 445k registers.

The reason for the inside loop is because I need to filter results obtained from another RecordSet, and then get these new results and compare.

Would it be better to use other methods, or other way? Is there another way to get specific data from a table(a faster way, of course)? Should I try multithreading?

Since people might need my code:

```
Private Sub btnGetQ_Click()
    Dim tabEQ As DAO.Recordset: Dim tabT7 As DAO.Recordset: Dim tabPesqC As DAO.Recordset: Dim PesqCqdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim index As Integer: Dim qtdL As Long: Dim qtdL2 As Long
    Dim arrC() As String: Dim arrC2() As String: Dim arrC3() As String

    Set tabEQ = dbC.OpenRecordset("EQuery", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set tabT7 = dbC.OpenRecordset("T7Query", dbOpenSnapshot)
    If Not tabEQ.EOF Then
        tabEQ.MoveFirst
        qtdL = tabEQ.RecordCount - 1
        ReDim arrC(qtdL): ReDim arrC2(qtdL)

        If Not tabT7.EOF Then
            tabT7.MoveFirst: index = 0
            Do Until tabT7.EOF
                arrC(index) = tabT7.Fields("CCO"): arrC2(index) = tabT7.Fields("CCE")

                Set PesqCqdf = dbC.QueryDefs("pesqCCO")
                PesqCqdf.Parameters("CCO") = arrC(index)
                Set tabPesqC = PesqCqdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

                qtdL2 = tabPesqConj.RecordCount - 1

                If qtdL2 > 0 Then
                   ReDim arrC3(qtdL2)

                   Dim i As Integer
                   For i = 0 To UBound(arrC3)
                       arrC3(i) = tabPesqC.Fields("CCE")
                       tabPesqC.MoveNext
                   Next
                End If

                On Error GoTo ERROR_TabT7

                index = index + 1: tabT7.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

ERROR_TabT7:
Set tabT7 = Nothing

End If
If IsObject(tabEQ) Then Set tabEQ = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA has no support for multithreading.

Comment: Try to use SQL. For futher help please provide more details. You might post an example with simplified source recordsets and output just to show the idea. What are the sources of the recordsets, are they disconnected recordsets? What kind of filtering should be applied?

Comment: The sources are native tables

Comment: Actually, two of them are getting the records from Querys

Comment: But I already tried Temporary Querys and it didn't improve anything

Comment: Might I suggest posting your actual code - as it'll make it infinitely easier to make suggestions on how you can improve it, if we can see it...

Comment: I've just uploaded my code

Answer (score 0):

I created tables linked with what i wanted :/